# Excel Vba Filter Range By Each Unique Value and Copy Data

Tags: vba, excel

Good Day All!

Im creating a macro and have never worked with filters and sorting before. I tried searching for something similar but couldn’t find - solutions I found is simple sort ascending or descending; or I`m phrasing it in a wrong way. 
Hope you can help me.

I have data that looks like this:

```
VENDOR#  ITEM#

VENDOR1 310001

VENDOR1 310002

VENDOR2 310013

VENDOR2 310006

VENDOR2 310012
```

There can be variable amount of items belonging to same vendor, and amount of vendors is dynamic.

These are rough steps that I would like macro to do:

1. Macro should filter each Vendor one by one (amount of vendors is dynamic), select all values that belong to it and copy. (**I need help on this step**)

As example with above data it would select Vendor1 as first filter copy info from columns a & b for both row1 and row2.

2. From there I will send an email to that Vendor with data it copied. (**No need help on this step**)
3. Continue to step 1 until last value in filter. (**I need help on this step**)

Thanks everyone who will look into this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list of all the vendors in a separate place and remove duplicates.
Then use this list as an array to filter for individual vendors. Then you can put the data for each vendor in a separate sheet. Here's the code for this, assuming the data you provided above is put in the cells G1:H6.

```
Sub Macro2()

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("K1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

    Dim num_vendors
    num_vendors = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count - 1
    Range("G1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.AutoFilter

For i = 1 To num_vendors
    Range("G1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Cells(i + 1, 11).Value

    Range("G1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    Sheets(i + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets(1).Select
Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

The first half of the code copies the vendor list and pastes it in K1. Then removes duplicates, determines the number of vendors from the remaining list, then goes back to G1 and enables filtering.

The second half of the code uses a for loop to filter the table for each vendor one by one, copy the visible cells, insert a sheet at the end of all sheets, switch to that sheet, paste the copied data and then go back to the original sheet.

This code should work regardless of the number of vendors of the number of rows for each vendor.

Comment: Thats amazing!
Thank you @gouravkr so much!

This simple line solves it all for me!

   `Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Cells(i + 1, 11).Value`

Thanks again!